# Upgrade from 11 to 12 not working solo mine

Tags: solo-mining

I am solo mining.
I just downloaded the new version GUI (v0.12.0.0) unzipped and ran the GUI. It does not sync the block chain and will not mine. I went back to 11 and after several minutes of working with the block chain it mines. Can someone PLEASE give me clear instructions on upgrading from 11 to 12 that works and solo mines!

Comment: It's because you're on the wrong (alternative) chain. You should be able to resolve your issue with that ^ guide. In addition, see my post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8cut4b/payment_not_show_up_in_wallet/dxi1e5r/).

Comment: Maybe this is an Issue with a lot of people because I don't recall being told by the GUI that it's time to update a new version is out.

Comment: I got it working now after purging the blockchain; and letting it sync. I no longer can see h/s rate at the bottom of the GUI is it hiding somewhere else?

Comment: You should be able to see it if you press the `Show status` button (on the `Settings` page of the GUI).